# JMeter cookie handling

Tags: session, cookies, jmeter

I have a JMeter test script that performs logon to a website. I can see the POST request with the appropriate information, but it seems the session is lost after that point, as the next step goes to the homepage expecting to be authenticated but isn't. Any ideas? I can post the code if necessary. I do have a cookie manager configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably it's due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), cookies might be not the only one dynamic parameter which you need to take care of, modern web applications widely use others for i.e. [client-side state tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386448(v=vs.100)) or [security purposes](https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf).

So inspect your test script and check for parameters which are dynamic, the easiest way is recording the same scenario once again and comparing resulting [.jmx scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan). Everything which differs is a subject to correlation.

More information: [How to Handle Correlation in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)

Comment: Hello, I did a recording using the correlation plugin and found no differences in the script

Comment: I think I figured it out, because it appears to be working now. I think (I did a number of things this morning, lol) that I had the wrong POST URL. The LTPA token wasn't being generated and applied, but it is now. Thanks!